# The simplest way to check if a visitor is logged with facebook or not

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am develop a plugin for wordpress where I want a simple way to check if a guest of a page is login with facebook or not.
I tried with the javascript SDK, but for this error:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Would be a crazy that every user of the plugin will must create her own Facebook app.

There is a simplest way to check if a visitor of a page is logged with facebook or not than JavaScript SDK?

Maybe with the facebook cookie name? or other flow?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, there is no officially supported way to check if a person is logged into Facebook except using the SDKs. Even if you could fine one, they might break as soon as Facebook changes the slightest thing so you would be better off using the official SDKs provided.